# I am not very beginner of coding in java, But I need some help in understanding the constructor in java

Tags: java

```java
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Why is the `new` keyword used even inside `BufferedReader`? Why won't it work without a "new" keyword? I have been doing this mistake and getting stuck in the middle.

Comment: yah i just tried as a "trail and error" to see if there would be any response.

Answer (score 7):

You're calling the `InputStreamReader` constructor to create a new `InputStreamReader`, then passing that as an argument to the `BufferedReader` constructor. It might be easier for you to understand by introducing a new local variable:

```java
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
```

This is a good general technique for understanding a complex statement - breaking it into multiple statements by using local variables can make it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To construct a `BufferedReader` object you will need `InputStreamReader` object, as per the constructor requirement. Now either you can create `InputStreamReader` separately and use it while constructing `BufferedReader` object using it's constructor or you can directly **create** and **use** there itself. The one in your code snippet the case where you can creating ans using it right there.

> Note - its **not** necessary that you will always use a **new** to construct
>   an object, new is used to create the object using its exposed
>   **constructors**, however some classes might expose **builders** or other ways to
>   create objects, in such cases even new might not be required.